# LocalDB deploy issue

Tags: .net, localdb

Working on a VB.NET project with SQL Server LocalDB I'm having this problem:

When deploying on a client machine (Windows 7), my application tries to create a database on disk but it got ERROR 5 (Access denied)... (it seems `SQLLocalDB` does not have write permissions on disk)

It suppose I have not chance to manipulate that machine. I just send a SETUP that contains the program and `SQLLocalDB` as prerequisite.

How can I solve this issue from code since I cannot access to client machine?

Thanks.

Comment: `LocalDB` is intended as a **developer** tool - it isn't intended to be used in production. If you want to deploy your database, use SQL Server - Express or any other edition (other than Compact Edition).

Answer (score 1):

The user running your application might not have access to the folder used by LocalDB default instance `(LocalDB)\v11`.
You could try creating your own instance first and using it to create your new database.

Calling [SqlLocalDB utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx) from command line:

1. `sqllocaldb create "MY_INSTANCE" -s`
2. Use `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MY_INSTANCE` within your connection strings.

Using C# code and [SQL LocalDB Wrapper library](https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb):

```
ISqlLocalDbProvider provider = new SqlLocalDbProvider();
ISqlLocalDbInstance instance = provider.GetOrCreateInstance("MY_INSTANCE");
instance.Start();
using (SqlConnection connection = instance.CreateConnection())
{
   connection.Open();
   // Create here your database
}
```